# Getting scipy.stats to ignore nan values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy, statistics

This is a follow-up to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56013641/pandas-histogram-ignoring-invalid-data-limit-x-range).

In this toy dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as stats
import numpy as np

dictOne = {'Name':['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'Fifth', 'Sixth', 'Seventh', 'Eighth', 'Ninth'],
           "A":[1, 2, -3, 4, 5, np.nan, 7, np.nan, 9],
           "B":[4, 5, 6, 5, 3, np.nan, 2, 9, 5],
           "C":[7, np.nan, 10, 5, 8, 6, 8, 2, 4]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dictOne)

column = 'C'

df2[df2[column] > -999].hist(column, alpha = 0.5)
param = stats.norm.fit(df2[column], nan_policy = 'omit')   # Fit a normal distribution to the data
print(param)
```

I'm trying to plot a histogram of one of the columns (which was what the previous question was about), with a normal distribution curve overlaid. `scipy.stats.norm.fit` is giving me `[nan, nan]` for `param`, even though I've used `nan_policy = 'omit'` in the function call.

How can I get it to ignore the NaN values in the dataframe to get some sensible statistics?

Comment: maybe drop na ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe `nan_policy` is a keyword used by `fit`.

In any case, you can just drop null values from the source dataset:

```
param = stats.norm.fit(df2[column].dropna())
```